# Finding/creating a GitLab CI docker image for running `spring-boot:build-image`

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gitlab-ci

I am having an issue with finding or creating a docker image that I can use on GitLab CI that will allow me to run `mvn package`, that in turn calls `spring-boot:build-image`

I have specified in my config that I need the `dind` container as a service, but I am unsure the best way to find a docker container that has docker, java and maven installed.

I am also not sure exactly how to create my own that I can then share for this purpose.

I am using dev containers for this project so I might try to snapshot that but that doesn’t seem the best for repeatability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the docker image `docker:24.0.7` I was able to add java 21 to it as part of the `before_script` to allow me to run both the docker commands and the java/maven (using the wrapper) ones.

The Docker image is built on Alpine so you can use `before_script: - apk add --update openjdk21`

You will need to pass the parameters to the pom file as variables for it to authenticate with GitLab for the push, logging on via the docker cli did not work.

```
                  <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>registry.gitlab.com/ssmale-spring-boot/springboot:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <docker>
                        <publishRegistry>
                            <url>${docker.publishRegistry.url}</url>
                            <username>${docker.publishRegistry.username}</username>
                            <password>${docker.publishRegistry.password}</password>
                        </publishRegistry>
                    </docker>
                </configuration>
```

.gitlab-ci.yaml

```yaml
variables:
  # Use TLS https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#tls-enabled
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

stages: 
  - build

create-and-publish-docker-image:      
  stage: build
  image: docker:24.0.7
  before_script:
    - apk add --update openjdk21 
  services:
    - name: docker:24.0.7-dind
      alias: docker
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code, building docker image and publishing..."
    - ./mvnw package 
      -Ddocker.publishRegistry.username=$CI_REGISTRY_USER 
      -Ddocker.publishRegistry.password=$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD 
      -Ddocker.publishRegistry.url=$CI_REGISTRY
    - echo "Maven Package complete"
  artifacts:
    name: "Learning"
    when: on_success
    expire_in: "30 days"
    paths:
      - "distro/target/distro-*.jar"
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not wrap maven in your project? If you then use a docker image with a jdk you can build and run it easily.

Please be aware that running with jdk is not best practice for production code.

Comment: Where do you find images with this and that? I have now wrapped maven so that would work. 

I don’t think there should be a jdk in the outputted image. From my reading the spring-boot:build-image command is creating a Production ready Docker container under the hood without the need for me to hand craft a Dockerfile